# How to call font family in curved text in fabric.all.min.js

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I had Created Curved Text based on [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/NHs8t/25/) .Now i want add font family to that curved text.when i add font family in curved text it will not render predefined function from fabric.all.min.js
Here my font family custom code and screenshot following below

```
            $('#font_bold').click(function() {
            var checked = $('#font_bold').attr('checked');
            if(checked =='checked') {
                Example.set('fontWeight',$(this).val()  ) ;
            }else {
                Example.set('fontWeight','100') ;
            }
            });
```

and i defined in font family in this [MY DEMO JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/vivek_27/5Unbh/1/) but i can't achieved it . how to solve it. Pls Guide me how to assign Font family in Curve text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
 this.group.item(i).setFontFamily  (this.opts.fontFamily)
```

Check the demo http://jsfiddle.net/vivek_27/5Unbh/1/ and replace the above line in the demo link.